# CodeJam not accepting my solution despite giving correct output (Parentning Partnering Returns problem)

Tags: c++

The following question can be found here: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27/000000000020bdf9

As the title says, I've written my solution and it gives all the correct outputs. My each submission simply says **Wrong Answer (test set skipped)** despite the outputs being correct.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool available(int S, int E, vector<vector<int>> tasks) {   
    if(tasks.size()==0) return true;
    else {
        for(int i=0; i<tasks.size(); i++) {
            if((S>=tasks[i][0] && S<tasks[i][1]) || (E>tasks[i][0] && E<=tasks[i][1]) || (S<=tasks[i][0] && E>=tasks[i][1])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

void assignTask(int S, int E, vector<vector<int>> &tasks) {
    if(0<=S && S<=E && E<=1440) {
        tasks.push_back({S, E});
    }
}


void solve() {
    int N;
    cin>>N;

    vector<vector<int>> JTasks, CTasks, time;
    // scheduling time
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int S,E;
        cin>>S>>E;
        if(0<=S && S<=E && E<= 1440) {
            time.push_back({S, E});
        }
    }
    // assign tasks
    bool possible=true;
    string str="";
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int S=time[i][0];
        int E=time[i][1];
        if(available(S,E,CTasks)) {
            assignTask(S,E,CTasks);
            char c='C';
            str.push_back(c);
            continue;
        } else if(available(S,E,JTasks)) {
            assignTask(S,E,JTasks);
            char j='J';
            str.push_back(j);
            continue;
        } else {
            possible=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(possible) cout<<str;
    else cout<<"IMPOSSIBLE";
    cout<<"\n";
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    int T, i=1;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--) {
        cout<<"Case #"<<i<<": ";
        solve();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Here are the expected outputs and my outputs:

```
Expected Output:
Case #1: CJC
Case #2: IMPOSSIBLE
Case #3: JCCJJ
Case #4: CC

My Output:
Case #1: CJC
Case #2: IMPOSSIBLE
Case #3: CJJCC
Case #4: CC
```

The only thing that is truly different from the expected output is Test case #3, but if you read the guidelines in the main page, it should be an acceptable answer (since this is a scheduling problem).

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Comment: Please provide all necessary information in the question itself and don't link to external resources. The question should be answerable without clicking links. Please provide a [mcve] with input data and expected output. It helps if you replace user input by hardcoded values.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't realize that Google Code Jam updated its policies to allow collaboration in qualification round.

I assume you already know that the sample tests aren't the only tests that are run against your solution on the server, so obtaining the correct results on them doesn't mean the code would be accepted.

Your solution is based on an incorrect assumption that assigning tasks to J and C in any order, as long as there are no ongoing conflicts, is optimal. Here is an example of when this won't work:

```
AAAAAAAA       BBBBBBBB
      CCCCCCCC
            DDDDD
```

Task A overlaps with task C, and task D overlaps with both B and C. You can assign A and D to one person, and C and B to another; however, your code would assign A and B to one person, and fail to assign C and D to another.

Comment: so in which order need?